# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/virtualCD’: Read-only file system

Tags: files, system, read-only

I just want to create a simple folder in root directory but I face this message:
`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/virtualCD’: Read-only file system`.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Is your media an USB drive ?

Comment: What is mounted at `/media/virtualCD`? Try `mount | grep /media/virtualCD` to find out and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the partition was mounted with the **errors=remount-ro option**, that means, if an error is encountered on the file system it will be remounted read-only.

You can try remounting the disk with read-write option.